# sub plotting odes15 MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

**I am trying to practice for a final coming up and I was given an old question and I am having trouble with the odes15 and sub plotting. I tried using the examples given on the MATLAB main website but couldn't figure out why it would work. The question is:**

[image]
[image]

**This is my code:**

```
 function dx = problem1(t,x)

P1 = 0.028735 ;
P2 = 0.028344 ;
P3 = 5.035 * 10^(-5) ;
Vi = 12 ;
n = 5/54 ;
D(t) = 3*exp(-0.05*t) ;
U = 3 ;

dx = zeros(3,1);
dx(1) = -P1*(G-Gb) - (X-Xb)*G + D(t) ;
dx(2) = -P2*(X-Xb) + P3*(I-Ib) ;
dx(3) = -n*I + U(t)/Vi ;

[T,X] = ode15s(@problem1, [0 24], [4.5 15 15]) ;
plot(T,X(:,1),'-',T,X(:,2),'-.',T,X(:,3),'.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You must constitute a M-function file named by `problem1` and write the code below. Then write the command[***] below in the command window. You will get an output like that:

[image]

```
function dx = problem1(t,x)     
    P1 = 0.028735 ;
    P2 = 0.028344 ;
    P3 = 5.035 * 10^(-5) ;
    Vi = 12 ;
    n = 5/54 ;
    D_t = 3*exp(-0.05*t) ;
    U_t = 3 ;
    Gb = 4.5;
    Xb = 15;
    Ib = 15;

    G = x(1);
    X = x(2);
    I = x(3);

    dx = zeros(3,1);
    dx(1) = -P1*(G-Gb) - (X-Xb)*G + D_t ;
    dx(2) = -P2*(X-Xb) + P3*(I-Ib) ;
    dx(3) = -n*I + U_t/Vi ;
end
```

[***] Write the code below to command window:

```
x0        = [4.5 15 15];
update    = 0.1;
t_span    = [0 update];
output    = x0;
time_axis = 0:update:24;


for k = 1 : 24 / update
    [T,X]  = ode15s(@problem1, t_span, x0) ;
    x0     = X(end, :);
    output = [output; x0];
end

figure, 

subplot(3, 1, 1)
plot(time_axis, output(:, 1), '-'); title('G')

subplot(3, 1, 2)
plot(time_axis, output(:, 2), '-.'); title('X')

subplot(3, 1, 3)
plot(time_axis, output(:, 3), '.'); title('l')
```

Comment: I think this is wrong, I kind of have an idea what it is intended to look like because I had a chance to have a small glimpse of the solution given by my professor. Plus it has to be sub plotted. Thanks for the help!!! I appreciate it!

Comment: I have edited my answer. New version is better to use. Btw, It was wrong because I didn't pay attention to measurement units. I don' t know but you know so you can adjust the variable. If it is useful, please accept as an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but it seems to be wrong, I'm pretty sure we are not supposed to use 'for' and the only command to use in the command window should only be calling the function. Sorry for the trouble again.

Comment: No problem. Btw, my mistake, I had forgotten the change arguments of ' ode15s() ' usage in the for loop. Look at the output figure in my answer, I have edited it again and if you want, you can omit the for loop, no biggie..

Comment: Okay so I am trying to put the code into one, so I do not have to enter anything in the command window other than "Problem1" while excluding using a for loop. If it isn't too much trouble can you show me how, I tried figuring it out for a good 30 min but it just isn't going through my head, the stress of finals is making me incompetent. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for your help!!